# What does $? mean in a shell if statement?

Tags: shell, csh

What is the meaning of the following statement in shell script?

```
if ($?REGRESS) then
....
endif
```

from where the given function is taking input from? This is a part of an old script which I am not able to understand.

Answer (score 2):

From the `csh` the man page:

```
$?name
${?name}
    Substitutes the string `1' if name is set, `0' if it is not.
```

But stop using `csh` (obligatory comment for future readers who may have somehow missed the memo that using `csh` is bad for you health).

Answer (score 0):

$? is a special variable. It stores the exit status of last command. If the last command runs successfully then it will be 0 and some other value for failure.